# Why is a cube, $I^3$, called three dimensional?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, manifolds

If $S^2$ is called a two dimensional sphere because locally it looks like a plane, why is $I^3$ called a three dimensional cube if locally it looks like a plane as well?

Comment: Are you sure that a box looks like a plane?

Comment: @BernardWojcik If we zoom in on one of the sides, then it is a plane. No?

Comment: I see, you are confusing the *surface* of the box with the box itself.

Comment: @BernardWojcik What do you mean?

Comment: The surface/exterior/boundary of a ball is 2 dimensional, but the ball itself is three dimensional.

Similarly, the surface/exterior/boundary of a cube is 2 dimensional, but the cube itself is three dimensional.

Comment: @BernardWojcik Got it. I see now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is already given in the comments: $I^3$ is by definition the Cartesian product of three intervals $I$, which is different from the "box", which is $\partial I^3$, the boundary of the three dimensional cube. The box $\partial I^3$ is indeed two dimensional.